# Map is not in right column

Tags: html, css

I am building a web app for school. The following screenshot is what I am looking to acheive.

[image]

However, the map is currently not taking the place of the right hand column

[image]

I feel as if I am missing something basic, but where am I going wrong? I am defining the class as the `col right`, but it seems to not be adhering to the class.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <head>
        <title> My Map </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col left">
                <div class="col left">
                    <h1 class="display-4">My Map</h1>
                </div>
                <div class ="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col left"></div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search a city">
                </div>
            </div>
        

                <div class="col right">

                    <div id="map"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
html {
   height: 100%;
}

#map {
   width: 45%;
   float: right;
   height: 500px; 
}


.column {
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 .left {
   width: 60%;
 }
 
 .right {
   width: 40%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class with *flex* property on *container-fluid* div.

Here is Html.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid wrap">
        <div class="col left">
            <div class="col left">
```

And here is CSS.

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

I just added a *wrap* class.